# Program type already present: com.android.internal.http.multipart.ByteArrayPartSource

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-install-apk

I am trying to create a build of my project but it's giving me error '''Program type already present: com.android.internal.http.multipart.ByteArrayPartSource'''. I understande some file in my dependency are duplicate. I have tried to exclude this group in various places but exactly couldn't find the correct way.

Following are the dependencies I am using

```
 implementation project(':segmentControlLibrary')
    implementation project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    implementation project(':webservice')
    implementation project(':PDFViewCtrlTools')
    implementation files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    //compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.3.1'
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.pdftron:pdftron:7.0.3'
    implementation ('com.pdftron:tools:7.0.3'){
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }

    implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

Can anyone help which module might contain the error prone group, which I need to exclude.

Note : I can run directly app in the device but not able to create debug or release apk.

Answer (score 0):

**remove**

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'`

you already declare material library above as

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: removed but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
android{
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
        exclude 'org/apache/http/version.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/client/version.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/entity/mime/version.properties'
    }
 }

dependencies {
    implementation project(':segmentControlLibrary')
    implementation project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    api project(':webservice')
    implementation files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.3.1'
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.pdftron:pdftron:7.0.3'
    implementation('com.pdftron:tools:7.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compileOnly files('libs/httpmime-4.5.10.jar')
    compileOnly files('libs/httpcore-4.4.12.jar')
    compileOnly files('libs/httpclient-4.5.10.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

Comment: now it gives Program type already present: com.pdftron.pdf.tools.BuildConfig...